# how to make a nested array in a foreach loop in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an array of data that contains 3 elements. I want to loop through that I can attach some numbers to it and place them in an index of array like below:

```
[
  "items" => array:3 [
    0 => "2021-08-28 00:00:00"
    1 => 1,
    2 => 3,
    ],
    [
    0 => "2021-08-29 00:00:00"
    1 => 1,
    2 => 3,
    ],
    [
    0 => "2021-08-30 00:00:00"
    1 => 1,
    2 => 3,
    ]
]
```

and here is what I did in my code :

```
 $test = [];
        foreach ($Date['date'] as $item) {
            if ($number = 1) {
                $test[]= $item;
                $test[]= 1;
                $test[]= 2;
            } }
```

and this is the result:

```
array:9 [
  0 => "2021-08-28 00:00:00"
  1 => 1
  2 => 2
  3 => "2021-08-29 00:00:00"
  4 => 1
  5 => 2
  6 => "2021-08-30 00:00:00"
  7 => 1
  8 => 2
]
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: you can push element to item
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-push

Comment: what is `$number`?

Comment: @CBroe what my wrong typing of comparison sorry . and by what i am doing wrong i meant what should i do :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```php
$test = [];
foreach ($Date['date'] as $item) {
    if ($number === 1) {
        $test[] = [$item, 1, 2];
    }
}
```

Comment: @Farshad: Is this answer helpful? Feel free to accept / upvote answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

You can push elements to laravel collection as follows.

```
foreach ($Date['date'] as $item) {
    if ($number === 1) {
        $item->push(1);
        $item->push(2);
    }
}
```

Or, you can even put key value pairs to the collection with put method.

more at: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-push